# CSS background-attachment fixed - out of flow?

Tags: css, background-position

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div id='container'>

    <div id='main'>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

```
div#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

div#main {
    background: #000000 url('images/bg_placeholder.jpg') no-repeat 85% 100px fixed;
    color:white;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

The #main is the same width as its #container.  Im trying to put a fixed background image on the top-right side of #main.  However, when I put the background-attachment:fixed, it seems to remove it from the flow...

In that, the image, does not get placed in the top-right of main, but seems like the top-right side of the page, or possibly the container.

In scroll mode, it sits great in the main.  it's only when a switch to fixed.

Is this how it works?  Is there a way around this?

Comment: you are doing `position: fixed;` for the subelement of #main?  Is that correct?

Comment: The title is clear: `background-position: fixed`... @dtj, can you show us your CSS source?

Comment: Finally, which one you set to `fixed`? `background-position` or `background-attachment`?

Comment: Im using the 'background' property, to set multiple params..but its the background-attachment that is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully this at least partially answers your question.

I've recreated your situation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ep6kQ/). Removing `background-attachment:fixed;` seems to fix your problem if I understand what you're trying to do correctly.

From [the Sitepoint article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-attachment) on `background-attachment`:

> The value fixed stops the background-image from scrolling with its
>   containing block. Note that although the fixed background-image may be
>   applied to elements throughout the document, its background-position
>   is always placed in relation to the viewport. This means the
>   background-image is only visible when its background-position
>   coincides with the content, padding, or border area of the element to
>   which it is applied. Thus, a fixed background-image doesn’t move with
>   elements that have a scrollbar—see overflow—because it’s placed in
>   relation to the viewport.

**EDIT:** Here's a possible way to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ep6kQ/3/

**EDIT EDIT:** Having issues getting the image to disappear when the user scrolls below the containing element. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: well I need the attachment to be fixed, so that it doesn't scroll.  Thats why Im doing fixed.  But your other comment answers my question, because I didn't know that fixed was relative to the viewport, so thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! See my edit for another way to possibly solve your problem. It's kind of hack-ish, but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Remove fixed and use your margin properties in CSS on the image. It's an ugly fix but it would probably work. Also might try using absolute instead of fixed. (I can't test at the moment, installing software.) Ugh.

Comment: Absolute positioning isn't an option for a background-position is it?

Comment: also, if I removed fixed, it will then scroll which, I can't have